# Variable comparison error

Tags: linux, bash, conditional-statements

Hello everybody and sorry for bad English!
I'm trying to make a "telegram alert" and made this conditional:

```
NOW=$(date +%s)
NOWCHECK=$((NOW-3))
[...]
if ("$DATE" < "$NOWCHECK"); then  # DATE is a string variable with seconds passed from 1/1/1970
...
fi
```

I get this error:

```
line 26: 1458939588: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're experiencing is Bash is trying to execute the expression within `(...)`. It's interpreted as running the `$DATE` command, and redirecting input to it from `$NOWCHECK`. But that's not what you want.

The operator for arithmetic operations is `((...))` not `(...)`. Do like this:

```
if (("$DATE" < "$NOWCHECK")); then
```

And it would be better to drop the `$` inside the `((...))`:

```
if ((DATE < NOWCHECK)); then
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if [[ "$DATE" -lt "$NOWCHECK" ]];   # -lt: less than
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this two variables set:

```
NOW=$(date +%s)    NOWCHECK=$((NOW-3))
```

Then: Either switch to correct Arithmetic Expansion `(( ... ))`

```
if (( NOW < NOWCHECK )); then
...
fi
```

Or remove the `<` character (which is interpreted as a redirection and presents an error as the source file named as the value of `NOWCHECK` does not exist):

```
if [[ $NOW -lt $NOWCHECK ]]; then
...
fi
```

---

```
if [ "$NOW" -lt "$NOWCHECK" ]; then
...
fi
```